# How to merge lines from shapefile using PyShp and Shapely and save them in a new shapefile?

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, linestring, pyshp

I have files with line segments that cover road network of towns. The issue is that each street with specific name consists of smaller segments that I need to merge into one line covering the whole street.

What I tried in the code below is to read a shapefile, create dictionaries where under a streetId are all of the street's segments and then merge it using ops.linemerge. The problem I have is when saving to the file in the following line

```
w.line(merged_line)
```

The error shown is

```
    w.line(merged_line)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 1977, in line
    self._shapeparts(parts=lines, shapeType=shapeType)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 2062, in _shapeparts
    for part in parts:
TypeError: 'LineString' object is not iterable
```

What object should I provide to the writer's line method? Is there any better way to merge the segments into streets?

```
import shapefile as shp
from shapely import geometry, ops
from shapely.geometry import shape

sf = shp.Reader("shapefiles/town1")
streetShapeDictionary = {}
streetSegmentDictionary = {}
shapes = sf.shapes()
records = sf.records()
fields = sf.fields

recordIndex = 0;
for record in records:
    streetId = record[0]
feature = sf.shapeRecords()[recordIndex].shape.__geo_interface__
linestringShape = shape(feature)
if streetId in streetSegmentDictionary:#add street segment to the list
    streetSegmentDictionary[streetId].append(record)
    streetShapeDictionary[streetId].append(linestringShape)
else:#add new key to the street dictionary
    streetSegmentDictionary[streetId] = [record]
    streetShapeDictionary[streetId] = [linestringShape]
recordIndex = recordIndex + 1

w = shp.Writer('shapefiles/whole_streets')
w.field('name', 'C')
streetShapesArray = []
for street in streetSegmentDictionary:
    for shape in streetShapeDictionary[street]:
        streetShapesArray.append(shape)
    multiline = geometry.MultiLineString([*streetShapesArray])
    merged_line = ops.linemerge(multiline)    
    w.line(merged_line)
    w.record('streetName1')
    streetShapesArray = []
    
w.close()
```

Comment: `merged_line` is a Shapely geometry that you cannot use directly with   Pyshp. Use `w.line(list(merged_line.coords)list(merged_line.coords))`

Comment: cross-post  :  [How to merge lines from shapefile using PyShp and Shapely and save them in a new shp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062484/how-to-merge-lines-from-shapefile-using-pyshp-and-shapely-and-save-them-in-a-new)

Comment: @gene, your suggestion causes the similar error:
line 140, in <module>
    w.line(list(merged_line.coords))
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 1977, in line
    self._shapeparts(parts=lines, shapeType=shapeType)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 2069, in _shapeparts
    point = list(point)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Also, I assume the suggested solution was w.line(list(merged_line.coords)), right?

Comment: yes, you use only the list of  the coordinates of the LineString: `line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])` -> `list(line.coords)`-> `[(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)]`